# SharePoint website - Anonymous users not able to access Survey

Tags: permissions, anonymous-authentication, survey

Ours is a SharePoint 2010 public website. To enable anonymous access to website required settings have been done.

[image]

Visitors are able to access website anonymously.

We Created a Survey and want visitors of website to be able to respond to the survey. Thus, we gave All permissions to Anonymous users on the survey.

[image]

However whenever we try to access survey page it prompts for login.

Kindly let know what we are missing.

Comment: Hi Mohammed, I had checked that post. In my case the survey page itself is not loading!. Also had i checked Site Collection Administrator > Site Collection Features. There is no feature called "Limited-access user permission lockdown mode" Kindly suggest / unmark  it as duplicate. "I didn't a resolution for the issue with valid attemptes"

Comment: Sure I will open it back :), hope you find the correct answer